# Is there a way of reading HTML tags on the page that are not part of the DOM using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a Chrome Extension that reads meta tags from the current tab in order to display information about the current page to the user.

I've noticed that currently on YouTube, the meta tags containing information about the current video are not accessible via the DOM (open up the Dev Console and check out `document.head`, no meta tags about the current video are present), yet they are on the page if you look at the page source. I guess they are adding them using document.write as they don't want them part of the DOM.

Is there another way I can access these tags using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll("meta")
```

Will return all the meta tags.

meta tags to do not have to be inside `<head>` tags. That's just a convention not a requirement. It's also a convention that google doesn't follow. See their [html style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Optional_Tags)

Comment: This will not work as, as I stated in the question, the meta tags have *not* been added to the DOM. I mentioned using `document.head` merely because through looking at the page source on a youtube video you can see the meta tags in the head section, querying the DOM in any way will not display those tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full list of meta, before it's manipulated by javascript - try this in the console of a youtube video

```
fetch('').then(r=>r.text()).then(html=> {
    let p = new DOMParser(), 
        d = p.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    console.log(d.querySelectorAll('meta')); 
});
```

I see 71 meta tags in one example video

I'm sure this can be easily accomplished in a web extension